# What is the best way go invisible after respawning? (Riki)

Tags: dota-2

Riki's invisibility doesn't usually kick in after you respawn.  How can you activate it?

Comment: Er, if this is true it's a bug. I have never heard of this before, though.

Comment: Riki itself is anoying. It sort of deserve this "bug". :]

Comment: Any screenshot showing riki not invisible despite having the fade time kicked in?

Comment: This bug was fixed in the test patch today: http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=69544

Comment: "Riki: Fixed an issue with Permanent Invisibility on respawning."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No longer necessary due to bug fix** (Pointed out by Decency)

Old Answer:

Usually you have to wait until you can attack something, blink at something, or TP.

The newest way I've discovered to do it is simply click your boots 3 times.  This puts it back on agility or whatever you had it, but then allows you to go invisible.

Comment: I'm sad this is no longer relevant, because now people are less likely to read the advice "click your boots three times and think of home". Wait, you didn't say "and think of home"?